# Haskell guard function not loading, checking two variables

Tags: haskell

I have this following function. 
I want to check if both variables a and b are bigger than 0 and if thats the case 
they get add and if not they get subtracted. My function is not meant to make sense its only for testing purposes it should only load and work.

```
test a b
    |a && b > 0 = a+b
    |otherwise = a-b
```

and i get the following error:

```
No instance for (Num Bool) arising from the literal `0'
```

But  when I remove the "`&& b`" my function is working. Why is my function not working as how it is now, what does this error mean, and how can I make this function load?

Comment: Your title is (unintentionally) misleading, as there actually *is* a function named `guard` defined in `Control.Monad`. You are talking about the guard *syntax*.

Comment: The error is confusing because you made GHC guess the types of the variables at hand. With a proper type annotation, GHC can generate much better error messages -- this is why it is strongly recommended to do so, possibly even before starting to write the function definition. Type annotations are also a very useful piece of documentation for human programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a && b > 0` collapses as `a && (b > 0) => a && True` (assuming `b>0`). Since you can't AND two numbers, this fails, giving you the error you reported above since `(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool`

You instead want

```
test a b
    | a > 0 && b > 0 = a+b
    | otherwise      = a-b
```

Alternatively you could reverse your logic

```
test a b
    | a <= 0    = a-b
    | b <= 0    = a-b
    | otherwise = a+b
```

Comment: `a && b > 0` does not have implicit parentheses around `a && b`.  It has them around `b > 0`.  `(&&)` is precedence 3, `(>)` is precedence 4.

Comment: @DavidFletcher oh, hmm. I even checked that in ghci before I posted, then apparently ignored my tests and wrote the wrong thing :D. Fixing now.

Comment: In the original code, the compiler infers that the types of `a` and `b` are `Bool`, not that they are numbers. In other words, the type error is not due to trying to apply `&&` to two numbers, it is due to trying to apply `+` to two non-numbers (as well as using a numeric literal at type `Bool`). Indeed, if you define an `instance Bool` the original code compiles (but is certainly still wrong).